# Increase click area of dynamic link with css

Tags: css

I have a background image associated with a table column, in the centre of that table column i have a dynamic link, example below .

http://www.qrrw.net/v

As you can see the writing is a php link, Is there anyway to make the whole area of the background image clickable rather than just the text?

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `display: block;` on your `<a>`s.

By the way, those `<div>` with a `center` attribute (brrrrh) invalid your code. Consider remove them and, to not loose your layout, add this rule on your `<a>`s.

```
.manu1 a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 109px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so like my background image is td.manu so would i jsut make it td.manu a ?, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `display:block;` it might be helpful to put a little `padding:10px;` on that `<a>` as well.  Adjust the pixel amount as needed to cover the majority of the background image